# How to specify tool offset with G41 syntax

Tags: cnc, g-code

Let's say during a side milling operation, a 40mm dia tool is used, so an offset is specified using a syntax as follows:

```
G41 D4
```

From what I understand from the above syntax is that, D must be followed by a number obtained by dividing the tool dia by 10. Am I right? 
I've seen another example where a 25mm dia tool was used and the D there was followed by 2 and not 2.5 (25 divided by 10). How come?

Can you please explain how the number that must be followed by "D" must be obtained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should consider there are [many different dialects of G-code](https://www.reddit.com/r/CNC/comments/b9xsal/many_dialects_of_gcode/), you should always mentioned the specifications of the machine you are working with.

The `G41` as mentioned [here in LinuxCNC page,](http://linuxcnc.org/docs/2.6/html/gcode/gcode.html#sec:G41-G42) indicates the tool. When the value starts with a `D` it refers to the tool number not the diameter. So `D4` refers to the tool number `4` and `D2` refers to tool number `2`. Also

> if there is no D word the radius of the currently loaded tool will be used

so I think if you want to indicate the radius of the currently loaded tool you should put

```
G41 20
```

or

```
G41 12.5
```